# iOS How to add credential to ASCredentialIdentityStore

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, autofill

iOS uses the [ASCredentialIdentityStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/ascredentialidentitystore) to hold credential identities and provide users a chance to click them and get their respective credentials.

What is the proper syntax to [save credential identities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/ascredentialidentitystore/2977539-savecredentialidentities) to the ASCredentialIdentityStore?

I tried like this:

```
let store = ASCredentialIdentityStore.shared
let passwordIdentity = ASPasswordCredentialIdentity(serviceIdentifier: ASCredentialServiceIdentifier(identifier: "stackoverflow.com", type: .URL), user: "userTest", recordIdentifier: nil)
               
store.saveCredentialIdentities([passwordIdentity]) { (success, error) in
                if success {
                    //great
                } else if let err = error {
                    //(.error(err))
                }
            }
```

Error:

1. Editor placeholder in source file (This is showing up at the error argument in the saveCredentialIdentities call.)
   Note: The other error I was having was solved by putting brackets around the credential identity argument.

I know, I need to get better at SWIFT and I should do a lot of reading, but I'm just trying to get this autofill provider functional. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you haven't replace the placeholder text `identities` with the value you want to save, which would be an array containing your identity `[passwordIdentity]`

Comment: Ahhh, I had previously saved identities and forgot to switch it back, hence the 'cannot find'. Was having two separate errors prior. The brackets, however solved that problem, so thanks. I still have the 'Editor placeholder in source file' error. Going to edit my question to show that more clearly.

Comment: Placeholder text just refers to text that Xcode has put in as part of code completion; you need to replace the gray placeholder text with your code.

Comment: I have tried printing, etc. within the success and error bodies. Same result. The error seems to appear in the at the error declaration of this line: store.saveCredentialIdentities([passwordIdentity]) { (success, error)

Comment: Try just deleting and re-entering that line.  Sometimes Xcode gets confused - It is saying that there is placeholder text provided by the editor that you haven't replaced.

Comment: That didn't work, but just building it did. Pretty annoying. Code still doesn't seem to be working, but that is probably a separate issue related to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As always with new features of apple, its is not extensively documented. I had to watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/721/) all over again to get the proper details from it, but it kinda provides most of the relevant facts and caveats.

Its good practice to first check if the store is available by checking it's state. What i did is `if state.isEnabled{ ...` but if you want proper error handling you should do something like this
`guard state.isEnabled else { throw Error}`

Also its very important to provide a recordIdentifier, otherwhise you will never properly be able to find the data from your own database. Try something like a uuid.

This is how i do it and it works:

```
let store = ASCredentialIdentityStore.shared
store.getState { state in
    if state.isEnabled {
        let credential = ASPasswordCredentialIdentity(
            serviceIdentifier: ASCredentialServiceIdentifier(identifier: "www.stackoverflow.com/", type: .URL),
            user: "Username",
            recordIdentifier: "my_reference_to_the_password_data")

        store.saveCredentialIdentities([credential]) { bool, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Saved Credential!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```